# What overhead ormLite has when querying or creating object with ForeignCollection?

Tags: performance, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a table with Players and an other table with Games. There is Player----(1..n)[Game] relationship between them (field definitions may not be entirely correct):

```
// Player
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;
@DatabaseField
public String name;

@ForeignCollectionField(
    eager = true,
    maxEagerLevel = 3)
public ForeignCollection<Game> games;


// Game
@DatabaseField
String title;

@DatabaseField
String playerName;
```

I would like to get and return a list of all games. When is the overhead letting ormLite do the select for the ForeignCollection? Or would it be better to do something like this:

```
    final List<Game> allGames = daoGames.getAllGroupedByName();
    final List<Player> allPlayers = gameDao.getAll();

    final HashMap<String, List<Game>> games = new HashMap<String, List<Game>>();
    for (Game currentGame : allGames) {
        final String player = currentGame.playerName;
        if (games.get(player) == null) {
            games.put(player, new ArrayList<Game>());
        }
        final List<Game> gamesOfPlayer = games.get(player);
        gamesOfPlayer.add(currentGame);
    }
    for (Player player : allPlayers) {
        player.games = games.get(player.name);
    }
```

My guess is ormLite would do a query for each and every player. Is it a big overhead compared to the one daoGames.getAllGroupedByName() (though the groupBy is not even needed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is ormLite would do a query for each and every player. Is it a big overhead compared to the one daoGames.getAllGroupedByName() (though the groupBy is not even needed)?

This is correct.  ORMLite does not do this very efficiently with a separate query for each `Player` result.  Your mechanism to do the `getAll()` and match them up by hand would most likely be faster.

I'd use an `ArrayList` unless you really need `LinkedList` capabilities.

Comment: On the list implementation: in this specific case the list would be traversed only, which is O(n) (same would be for the ArrayList). Initialising is a bit faster with LinkedList, because the size is not known in advance, so reallocation would be needed for the ArrayList (except if it is initilised with allGames.size()). But you are right, in general the ArrayList is probably better. Though the LinkedList generates more garbage objects, which will need to be collected. Hm. At the end I might switch to ArrayList :-)

Comment: In general `ArrayList` is a lot better unless you are talking about tons of objects that are removed or relocated in the `List`.